# Replacing chunks of numpy array on condition

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Let's say I have the following numpy array, of 1's and 0's exclusively:

```
import numpy as np

example = np.array([0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1], dtype=np.uint8)
```

I want to group all elements into chunks of **3**, and replace the chunks by a single value, based on a condition.
Let's say I want **[0,1,1]** to become **5**, and **[0,1,0]** to become **10**.
Thus the desired output would be:

```
[5,10,5]
```

All possible combinations of 1's and 0's in a chunk have a corresponding unique value that should replace the chunk. What's the fastest way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can have a dict that maps the 8 possible values of 0s and 1s to the arbitrary numbers you want, and then you translate based on reading the array three indices at a time and getting the value from the dict

Comment: I could, but this would be too slow for my use case. I'm looking for a vectorized way to achieve this.

Comment: `np.packbits` does what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers indicated, you can start by reshaping your array (actually, you should probably generate it with the correct shape to begin with, but that's another issue):

```
example = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=np.uint8)
data = example.reshape(-1, 3)
```

Now running a custom python function over the array is going to be slow, but luckily numpy has your back here. You can use [np.packbits](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html) to transform each row into a number directly:

```
data = np.packbits(data, axis=1, bitorder='little').ravel() # [6, 2, 6]
```

If you wanted `101` to map to `5` and `110` to map to `6`, your job is done. Otherwise, you will need to come up with a mapping. Since you have three bits, you only need 8 numbers in the mapping array:

```
mapping = np.array([7, 4, 3, 8, 124, 1, 5, 0])
```

You can use `data` as an index directly into `mapping`. The output will have the type of `mapping` but the shape of `data`:

```
result = mapping[data]  # [5, 3, 5]
```

You can do this in one line:

```
mapping[np.packbits(example.reshape(-1, 3), axis=1, bitorder='little').ravel()]
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you reshape your array in to a 3 by something array. Now we can see each row as a binary number that's an index into a list of values that you want. You convert it to that number and index into the values.

```
arr = np.array([0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1], dtype=np.uint8).reshape(-1,3)

idx = 2**0*arr[:,0]+2**1*arr[:,1]+2**2*arr[:,2]

values = np.zeros(2**3)
values[0 *2**0+ 1 *2**1+ 1 *2**2] = 5
values[0 *2**0+ 1 *2**1+ 0 *2**2] = 10

values[idx]
```

this gives

```
array([ 5., 10.,  5.])
```

Or if you prefer to write the conversion more succinctly though a bit less elementary (thanks to @mozway for the idea):

```
def bin_vect_to_int(arr):
    bin_units = 2**np.arange(arr.shape[1])
    return np.dot(arr,bin_units)


arr = np.array([0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1], dtype=np.uint8).reshape(-1,3)
idx = binVecToInt(arr)

values = np.zeros(2**3)
values[bin_vect_to_int(np.array([[0,1,1]]))] = 5
values[bin_vect_to_int(np.array([[0,1,0]]))] = 10

values[idx]
```

Comment: Nice (+1), simpler method to compute the binary: `(example.reshape(3,-1)*2**np.arange(3)).sum(1)`

Comment: @mozway well when you're already multiplying and summing up you might as well use `np.dot` no?

Comment: Yes very true, you can do `np.dot(example.reshape(3,-1),2**np.arange(3))` ;)

Comment: @mozway well I am

Comment: I see that (sorry, small screen, on phone)

Comment: @mozway, Or `np.packbits`

Answer (score 1):

You can use contiguous array view of `shape(3, -1)`, find locations of unique occurences and replace them in these locations:

```
def view_ascontiguous(a): # a is array
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
    return a.view(void_dt).ravel()

def replace(x, args, subs, viewer):
    u, inv = np.unique(viewer(x), return_inverse=True)
    idx = np.searchsorted(viewer(args), u)
    return subs[idx][inv]

>>> replace(x=np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]).reshape(-1, 3),
        args=np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]),
        subs=np.array([ 5, 57, 58, 44, 67, 17, 77,  1]),
        viewer=view_ascontiguous)
array([17, 57, 17])
```

Note that here `idx` means locations of unique [contiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998223/what-is-the-difference-between-contiguous-and-non-contiguous-arrays) blocks of length N in a [Power Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) `{0, 1}^N`.

In case `viewer(args)` maps `args` to `[0, 1, 2, 3, ...]` inside `np.searchsorted` method, replacing it with `np.arange(len(args))` helps to improve performance.

This algorithm could be also used in more general problem:

---

You are given array of `dtype=np.uint8` of `M*N` values 0 & 1. You are also given a mapping between Power Set `[0, 1]^N` (all possible blocks of length `N` of 0 & 1) and some scalar values. Find an array of `M` values following these steps:

- Split array you are given into `M` contiguous blocks of length `N`
- Replace each block with scalar value using a mapping you are given

---

Now, fun part: you can use your own `viewer`. It is required to map an array you pass in `args` to any kind of ascending indices like so:

```
viewer=lambda arr: np.ravel_multi_index(arr.T, (2,2,2)) #0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
viewer=lambda arr: np.sum(arr * [4, 2, 1], axis=1) #0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
viewer=lambda arr: np.dot(arr, [4, 2, 1]) #0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

Or even more fun:

```
viewer=lambda arr: 2*np.dot(arr, [4, 2, 1]) + 1 #1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15
viewer=lambda arr: np.vectorize(chr)(97+np.dot(arr, [4, 2, 1])) #a b c d e f g h
```

since you could also map

`[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]`

to any ascending sequence you could think of like `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]` or `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']`
and the result remains the same.

#### Further notes

Thanks @MadPhysicist,

`np.packbits(example.reshape(-1, N), axis=1, bitorder='little').ravel()`

also does the trick. It's pretending to be the fastest solution since `np.packbits` is optimised quite well in `numpy`.

Comment: This seems a bit more complicated (time-complexity-wise) than warranted by the problem.

Comment: Rather than using `void`, you can add an extra column of zeros, and just view as `np.uint32`. You can map that to simple indices 0-8 much more easily with bit-twiddling or just use `np.packbits`

Comment: It's a good idea. I didn't notice that use case of `np.packbits`. It seems like your method is the most performant in all the solutions. It won't work in case `N > 8` of my general problem due to specific behaviour of `np.packbits`. There are some work arounds though.

Comment: It'll work on most systems with `N` up to 64. Especially nicely after the fix I did here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/20722. All you have to do is view the output as a `uint64`

Comment: @mathfux really "It's pretending to be the fastest solution"? So it's not actually the fastest? I think this should be rephrased. But it's a cool implementation of the idea.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Great Job! I'm a little bit lazy but you could also try to compare complexity of your solution to general problem with mine. I assume `N = length of block`, `M = number of blocks` and `R` = proportion between distict blocks met and the length of Power Set (`2^N`) is a good idea to start with.

Comment: I think we have slightly different premises. You solve the general problem of a mapping of possible patterns (which really don't have to be 0-1 at that point), to some other arbitrary quantity. I assume that all combinations of 0 and 1 are possible, which A) limits N to 64 on most system, and B) implies that the user must provide the full 2**N sized mapping on output. My solution if faster because it solves a much simpler problem. You use sorting because numpy does not support hash tables, I use a couple of linear passes over the array.

Comment: @user2640045 Well, it relates strongly not only with complexity but also with performance of `numpy` methods such as `unique` vs `packbits` while using it over `views` or other kinds of mappings. Timings of both algorithms are needed but I'm just leaving them out of scope. There are some ways to [outperform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70712915/how-do-i-optimise-numpy-packbits-with-numba) `np.packbits`, however, but they are based on `numba` instead `numpy`.

Comment: As far as complexity goes, I would solve the problem you are solving using a hash table. Practically, it would always be slower in python, but complexity wise it would offer an O(n) solution where you are forced to use O(n log n) by the limitations of numpy.

Comment: @mathfux. Keep in mind that `np.unique` is `np.sort, np.diff, np.flatnonzero` wearing a trenchcoat.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Good point. I didn't check a source code of `np.unique` and I didn't know `np.diff` & `np.flatnonzero` is hidden behind `np.unique`

Comment: @mathfux. It may not be literally that. The important part is that it's sort-based, which makes it `O(n log n)`. The steps after that are *equivalent* to `np.diff`, `np.flatnonzero`, but they may be implemented in C. I never checked, because it's not important what the O(n) portions are doing.